# How to create a service account for a bigquery dataset from the cli

Tags: google-bigquery

I've found instructions how to generate credentials for the project level but there aren't clear instructions on adding a service account to only a specific dataset using the cli.

I tried creating the service account:

```
gcloud iam service-accounts create NAME
```

and then getting the dataset:

```
bq show \
--format=prettyjson \
project_id:dataset > path_to_file
```

and then adding a role to the access section

```
    {
      "role": "OWNER",
      "userByEmail": "NAME@PROJECT.iam.gserviceaccount.com"
    },
```

and then updating it. It seemed to work because I was able to create a table but then I got an access denied error `User does not have bigquery.jobs.create permission in project` when I tried loading data into the table.

When I inspected the project in the cloud console, it seemed as if my service account was added to the project rather then the dataset, which is not what I want but also does not explain why I don't have the correct permissions. In addition to owner permissions I tried assigning editor permission and admin, neither of which solved the issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not possible for a service account to only have permissions on a dataset level and then run a query. When a query is invoked, it will create a job. To create a job, the service account to be used should have permission `bigquery.jobs.create` added at a project level. See [document](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/running-jobs#required_permissions) for required permissions to run a job.

With this in mind, it is required to add `bigquery.jobs.create` at project level so you can run queries on the shared dataset.

NOTE: You can use any of the following pre-defined roles as they all have `bigquery.jobs.create`.

- roles/bigquery.user
- roles/bigquery.jobUser
- roles/bigquery.admin

With my example I used **roles/bigquery.user**. See steps below:

1. Create a new service account (**bq-test-sa@my-project.iam.gserviceaccount.com**)
2. Get the permissions on my dataset using `bq show --format=prettyjson my-project:mydataset > info.json`
3. Add OWNER permission to service account in `info.json`

> ```
> {
>   "role": "OWNER",
>   "userByEmail": "bq-test-sa@my-project.iam.gserviceaccount.com"
> },
> ```

4. Updated the permissions using `bq update --source info.json my-project:mydataset`
5. Check BigQuery > mydataset > "SHARE DATASET" to see if the service account was added.

> [image]

6. Add role **roles/bigquery.user** to service account using `gcloud projects add-iam-policy-binding myproject --member=serviceAccount:bq-test-sa@my-project.iam.gserviceaccount.com --role=roles/bigquery.jobUser`

Comment: In this scenario you are adding it to both the dataset and the project. What's the point of adding it to the dataset as well, won't it be inherited from the project where you add it in step 6? Or will this somehow prevent them from editing other datasets? We'd like seperate credentials for each data set so their isnt any accidental crossovers, that's why I've been trying to add only dataset level permissions.

Comment: The set role won't be inherited at a dataset level since [bigquery.jobUser](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/access-control#bigquery) can be granted at the project level only. Also `bigquery.jobUser` only allows the SA to create jobs, but not to access any dataset. So in this example "bq-test-sa" can only access "mydataset" since the SA was granted permission at dataset level. But if you use  "bq-test-sa" to access another dataset, it will show a permission error.